# How to pass a variable to a script in user_data

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to run a bash script file in user_data that prompts the user for a domain. Here is the domain part of the commands that are of .sh file itself.

```
DOMAIN=$1
if [ -z $1 ]
then
echo ""
printf "Enter the domain you want to host BookStack and press [ENTER]\nExamples: my-site.com or docs.my-site.com\n"
read DOMAIN
fi
```

I would like to pass my EIP, aws_eip.one.public_ip as an input to the script.

Here is the actual commands that are run in the user_data section.

```
#!/bin/bash
      sudo apt install wget
       # Ensure you have read the above information about what this script does before executing these commands.
      sudo apt install -y wget
      
      # Download the script
      wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BookStackApp/devops/main/scripts/installation-ubuntu-18.04.sh

      # Make it executable
      chmod a+x installation-ubuntu-18.04.sh

      # Run the script with admin permissions
      sudo ./installation-ubuntu-18.04.sh $ (this is where I would like to pass my eip variable)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You would probably have to use this script with the `templatefile` function: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile.

Answer (score 3):

Get the IP from the [ec2 metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) in your user data:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```